# Exporting to Excel does not export all rows in Datatables

Tags: datatables

Im using datatables for displaying data on the webpage. Have also added and Export button which would export the data in Excel format.
 Currently im using search() (based on column no. 17) in the javascript to only show specific data in the datatables. On clicking export only the filtered data is being exported. I would want to export the entire data without any filter being applied.

1. in the view it should only show the rows where column 17 has a specific value 'abc' (Working)
2. While exporting, it should export entire data i.e column 17 should be having all values as without the search being applied. (Not Working)

Code Snippet:

```
var table = $('.tableContent').DataTable({    
        "autoWidth": false,    
        "pageLength": 50,    
        dom : 'lBfrtip',    
        buttons : [ {    
            extend : 'excel',    
            text : 'Export to Excel'    
        } ],

        "columnDefs" : [{    
            "targets" : [ 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11,  17, 18 ],    
            "visible" : true,    
            "searchable" : true    
        }, {    
            "targets" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21 ],    
            "visible" : false,    
            "searchable" : false    
        }]
    });
    table.column(17).search('abc', false, false, true).draw();
```